# Error writing to serial device in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, arduino

This is my code

```
import os
import sys
import serial
import datetime
string = datetime.datetime.now()
print(string)
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
print(ser.name)
ser.write(string)
ser.close
```

And I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\SW\Python 3.5\COM.py", line 9, in <module>
    ser.write(string)
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 301, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 61, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You don't seem to have posted the code that is causing your error. If you have, which line of the posted code is line 61?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` is not a `str`. It is a `datetime` object. Try converting it to `str` with `str(datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: Thats all code, 61 line is in lib

Comment: Thats great, but what have you done so far to try and fix it yourself?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\SW\Python 3.5\COM.py", line 9, in <module>
    ser.write(string)
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 301, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 58, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: %r' % (seq,))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '2016-01-07 14:12:29.707373'

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `bytes` object to `ser.write()`, but you are using `datetime.datetime.now()`, which is a `datetime` object.

You can coerrce the datetime object to a string using `str()`. Since you are using Python 3, you also need to convert the string to bytes before you can write it to the serial device.

```
date_string = str(datetime.datetime.now())
dates_bytes = date_string.encode('ascii')
ser.write(date_bytes)
```

Or, if you require a custom format, you can use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y")
date_bytes = date_string.encode('ascii')
ser.write(date_bytes)
```

Comment: Thank, I began learn this language yesterday, I'm 13. I understood that this problem in types of date and time.

Answer (score 0):

`now()` returns a DateTime object not a string. Even if you can print it, you can not write it to the serial directl. Use `str(string)` to explicitly convert it when writing.